# Calculating endpoint for a function so arc length equals l.

Tags: calculus, integration, derivatives

I'm trying to simulate a line hanging from a given point using a quadratic function.
The line is located at point $(x_0, y(x_0))$ where $y$ is my quadratic function.

Now, the line has length $l$, and I simulate it hanging and swinging from side to side by changing the quadratic and linear coefficient. This isn't really important in the problem, but I mention it just to give You a full picture.

Now, the problem is, that when I change the coefficients of the formula, the length of the line changes as well, and I have to pick a point $x_1$ in which the line will end so the length can stay the same.

Of course, the simplest way is just to pick a point $x_1$ such that distance from $(x_0, y(x_0))$ to $(x_1, y(x_1))$ is equal to $l$, but this actually calculates the straight-line distance, not the arc length, so for certain coefficeints this becomes really inacurate.

So, the proper way to find $x_2$ would be solving this equation:
$$\int_{x_0}^{x_1} \sqrt{1+f'(t)^2} dt = l$$

For a proper $x_1$. However, after integrating it's really complicated to "extract" $x_1$ from the equation.

Thinking about this, I have found a stupid idea that doesn't work, but I dont know why, and this is the main point of my question.

So, for this integral exists a antiderivative $F(x)$, so this whole equation can be represented as:
$$F(x_1) - F(x_0) = l$$
So:
$$F(x_1) = l + F(x_0)$$
Now, $l$ is a constant, and $x_0$ is set (I'm just solving for $x_1$), so $F(x_0)$ is a constant as well. This means, that I just can differentiate the whole equation over $x_1$ and get:
 $$F'(x_1) = 0 => \sqrt{1+f'(x)^2} = 0 $$

Which is obviously wrong, because it doesn't depend at all on values of $l$ and $x_1$.

So now, I have two questions:
1. Why is my differentiaton step wrong?
2. Is there any way to simplify solving for this integral?

Thank You so much for help with this problem!

Comment: When you differentiate a function w.r.t to a variable, you first differentiate in terms of the variable and then evaluate. What you are doing is differentiating $F(x_1)$ w.r.t $x$, which would be $0$, as $x_1$ is some fixed point

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Note: This is an incomplete answer as I only answer part 1.

---

For question 1:
This is the same as attempting to "solve" a quadratic equation as follows:
\begin{align}
x^2 + 3x + 2 &= 0\\
\implies\dfrac{d}{dx}(x^2 + 3x + 2) &= \dfrac{d}{dx}0\\
\implies 2x + 3 &= 0\\
\implies x &= -\dfrac{3}{2}
\end{align}

One can easily verify that $3/2$ is **not** a solution of the first equation.

The problem is the following:
When we write $x^2 + 3x + 2 = 0$, we do *not* mean that the written equation is an identity. That is, it is not true that $x^2 + 3x + 2 = 0$ for all $x \in \Bbb R$.
What we are writing is that there's some $x$ such that $x^2 + 3x + 2 = 0$. So it does not make sense to differentiate both sides with respect to $x$ since it does not hold for "variable" $x$. (If you recall, the derivative of a function is a limiting operation, whereas the above equation holds only for two "discrete" points.)

Answer (score 0):

For simplifying things, what I suggest is consider your hanging point the origin of your coordinate system, Hence $(x_0, y_0) = (0,0)$

Now, let the general quadratic passing through the point be of the form

$$y = ax^2 + bx$$

$$\implies y' = 2ax + b$$

Now, for curve length, we have

$$\int_0^{x^*}\sqrt{1+(2ax + b)^2}dx = L$$

Any further simplification is difficult, and you'd mostly end up using Lambert W functions to reverse solve for $x^*$.

Answer (score 0):

This is an answer only to question (1).

Your differentiation step isn't wrong. What is wrong is the conclusion you draw. What that gives you is that $$\sqrt {1+f'(x_0)^2}=0.$$

By the way this shows that $f'(x_0)$ is imaginary.